# Can your preview work item attahments in Azure devops other than images?

Tags: sql, azure-devops, attachment, tfs-workitem

I am using Azure Devops On Premises and have a number of sql scripts and text files attached to work items. It would be really useful to be able to preview these directly in the work item instead of downloading them. THe only files it seems to be able to preview are images.

Are there any extensions or settings that can do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to images, Azure Devops also supports previewing .txt files in work item.

**For other types of files**

I'm afraid that there is no such extension to preview the attachments( e.g. SQL scripts files) in work item at this moment.

This is [an under review feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/400773/provide-previewing-software-for-attachments-to-wor.html).

You could vote and add your comments for this feedback.